# Complete Compliance Requirements for your apple account

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store, apple-developer

I started facing this warning today

> Under the Digital Services Act, you must provide and verify
> information regarding your account. If you don't, there may be payment
> delays or your content may be removed from sale in certain countries
> or regions.
> Complete Compliance Requirements for Ashvin

Answer (score 3):

**Simply follow this steps**:

1. Click on link from warning "Complete Compliance Requirements for YOUR_ACCOUT_NAME"
   [image]

**OR**

1a. Goto your iTunes Account - https://appstoreconnect.apple.com

1b. Click on 'Business'

1. Now you will see the same warning in "Business" page.
   Click on same link again
   [image]
2. It will redirect on Business > Agreements, click on same link again
   [image]
3. Now there will be popup like this, if you're account is "non-trader provider account" then select the second option like in image. **For my case it was this option.**

More details [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-compliance-information/manage-european-union-digital-services-act-compliance-information/)

[image]

That's it! Good luck.

Comment: It would be better if you can attach this [source link](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-compliance-information/manage-european-union-digital-services-act-compliance-information/) so that others can understand and decide which option suit them the most. thank you

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://x.com/seraleev/status/1771169120597213657) explanation clarifies who should choose trader or non-trader, regardless of offering in-app purchases or selling an app.

Comment: I have app where we have login option where customer provide URL, username, and password. But this site subscription can paid subscription. We are not collecting money either from app store or in app and no ads displayed. Are we trader or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any monetization on your apps (IAP, Subscription, Ads etc. ), you need to chose a "Trader" account, if the apps you have are free to use, you can choose "Non-Trader".

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Any soure bro??

Comment: [source link](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-compliance-information/manage-european-union-digital-services-act-compliance-information/)  @Joe

Comment: what about if you only have apps for sale for $0.99? they do not contain any IAP or subscription or ads ! am I considered as a trader or no ?

Comment: If you make money from the app, you are a trader! Period.

Comment: Not everyone agrees to this across the board. Lot's of discussion on this topic on the web. But the effect of this law will sacrifice a lot of privacy for app developers.And for those who work around it, it adds extra recurring cost for creating PO boxes, etc.